# NPM Warning notsup Unsopported engine for gatsby-plugin

Tags: node.js, npm, gatsby, npm-install, gatsby-plugin

I am getting the following error when running the command `npm install gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager`

I tried updating the npm version by running `npm update -g` but when I check it, it's still "6.14.6".

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

```
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager@3.4.0: wanted: {"node":">=12.13.0"} (current: {"node":"10.22.0","npm":"6.14.6"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager@3.4.0
npm WARN gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager@3.4.0 requires a peer of gatsby@^3.0.0-next.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager@3.4.0 requires a peer of react@^16.9.0 || ^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager@3.4.0 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.9.0 || ^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager@3.4.0
updated 1 package and audited 3 packages in 0.68s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the npm that needs an update but rather Node.js. You are running Node.js 10.22.0, but the package `gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager@3.4.0` requires Node.js 12.13.0 or higher.

Given that support for Node.js 10.x ended a few days ago (on April 30 2021), that's another reason to update. At the current time, I'd recommend updating to 14.x which is the most recent LTS (long-term-support) release. 12.x is fine, though, and will be supported for another 12 months. (14.x will be supported for another 24 months. 16.x will be supported for another 36 months, but is not officially an LTS release until October, so lots of changes might happen with it that wouldn't happen in an LTS release.)

It's also worth noting that the package did in fact get installed. You received a warning about the Node.js version, but not an error. Still, I would not recommend trying to run the package with a version of Node.js that it says it does not support.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I updated Node.js and everything worked out just fine, I updated it by installing NVM (node version manager) and then running `nvm install node --reinstall-packages-from=$(nvm current)`